# SQL Server plus small files

Tags: sql-server-2005, filesystems, log-files

I have a MSSQL server, 3 volumes, that runs some processes that seem to take way too long. One of these processes reads in a zip file, then writes to a database based on what's in the zip file.... for each record. I have 2 volumes in use and am creating the third- so I am trying to plan how to do this. OS has to remain on vol. 1. The TLogs should probably go on the new volume and the mdf's on the existing vol.2.. Do I put the file store on the volume with the MDF's so they don't interfere with the TLog writes, or with the TLogs so they don't interfere with the TLog flush to the MDFs? I know it's best to have more servers / volumes but I have to make do with whats on hand for now. I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Much depends on what these "volumes" consist of, and what their I/O parameters are.

You need to specify every last detail of this setup if you expect usable answers.

Comment: OK. I'm a little more familiar with this particular setup now so I can give better information. The server is setup all wrong- That much goes without saying. It has two physical volumes, each composed of two drives in a RAID-1. The first volume has a 12GB system partition and a ~288MB data partition that contains 15 SQL databases and their TLOG and backup files. The second physical volume is 100% dedicated to a file structure that contains a ton of random user data files. The rest of the files on the drive fall into 1 of 2 categories: 100K or less PDFs and 300KB or less zip files.

Comment: So what I want to do is to determine the best storage configuration for the server. I am installing two more drives in another RAID-1 which will max out the 6 bays. I am going to move the extended partition with the database files to this new drive, assign the old extended partition letter to this drive, remove that partition, and relegate half of that space to the OS. What I need to know is how to optimize the storage for this setup- Should I format the drive with the ZIP and PDF files to a smaller allocation unit size? What measures would help improve the efficiency of the system?